# Mobaxterm terminal show line as funky characters

Tags: powershell, terminal, windows-terminal, mobaxterm

This is what I am seeing in the terminal
[image: What is seen in the terminal]

This is what I should see (displaying correctly in PowerShell):
[image: What I should be seen]

I did change the chatset to UTF-8, but it is still not working
[image: Applied settings]

Not sure what to do at this point, any help is greatly appreciated